# Asp .NET MVC OutputCache stored in SQL db

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, relational-database, outputcache

How can you configure OutputCache in Asp .NET MVC 2 (with .NET 3.5) so that the cached data is stored in SQL database?

Comment: would this not negate the reason for caching in the first place?

Comment: It depends. In my case the web application calls remote web service and every invocation takes up to 10 seconds.

Comment: would you not want to cache the results from the remote web service then rather then the output from your app?

Comment: @SamHolder, I absolutely agree with you but there are some conditions which force us to cache output from the web app rather than only the output from the remote web service. Thanks for your pertinent comments nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved in ASP.NET 4.0 where you can write a [custom cache provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). Quote from this very same blog post:

> One limitation of output caching with
>   ASP.NET V1->V3.5, though, is that the
>   cache store itself is not extensible –
>   and the cached content always has to
>   be stored in-memory.

Time to upgrade :-)